# FCM notification not reveived on Android

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use FCM to send notifications. I'm building an app using Xamarin, so I followed [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/) tutorial to set up my notifications.

Here my firebase service:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}

[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
    }

    void SendNotification(string messageBody)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .SetContentText(messageBody)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);

        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

I had an issue with the refresh token malfunctioning from time to time so I added this to my MainActivity:

```
if (IsPlayServicesAvailable())
        {

            var json = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("google_services.json")))
            {
                json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var options_from_json = JObject.Parse(json);

            try
            {
                var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .SetApplicationId(options_from_json["client"][0]["client_info"]["mobilesdk_app_id"].ToString())
                    .SetApiKey(options_from_json["client"][0]["api_key"][0]["current_key"].ToString())
                    //.SetDatabaseUrl("Firebase-Database-Url")
                    .SetGcmSenderId(options_from_json["project_info"]["project_number"].ToString())
                    .Build();
                var firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("L'app firebase existe déjà, donc il n'y a rien à faire.");
            }

            await Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 var instanceID = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
                 var iid1 = instanceID.Token;
                 var iid2 = instanceID.GetToken(options_from_json["project_info"]["project_number"].ToString(), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope);
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Iid1: {0}, iid2: {1}", iid1, iid2);
             });
        }
```

Fine, so far I've got token for emulators as well as real life devices.
My problem is the reception of notification: it's really hazardous, sometime I get some an instant after I hit send on FCM console, sometime I have to reboot the device, sometime it just takes hours to arrive and sometime I just receive nothing... My setup doesn't change and the devices aren't on a wifi.

Any clues?

Comment: I don't get how you implement `onTokenRefresh` but if somehow your trick cause many calls to `onTokenRefresh`, token of your installation changes frequently and that can have such effect (what you are experiencing) on receiving notification.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint: I followed the doc for onTokenRefresh which, apparently, is automatically called on due time. The thing is, I was forced to add the MainActivity part because, for some unknow reason, the app failed to instanciate properly the FirebaseApp (maybe due to a change in google-services.json + no fresh reinstall). I'll try dropping that part which is out of the tuto part.

Comment: Ok, so here is the thing: I changed nothing to my code and get the push notifications to work properly.
Here is the thing: I launched the App in debug via VS to retrieve its firebase token. I killed the app which made me go out of Debug. I relaunched the App and then kill it again. I sent various notifications from the firebase console: no problem. Looks like having the debugger attached to the app prevented the emus and phones from receiving the push notifications. It's working and repeatable but I would be interrested in knowing why.